# How to get names, profile pictures of friends

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-fql

Can someone help with code for a sample Facebook application which just gets all the friends name, and images and prints them to the status? I tried some code provided in Facebook's site, but for some reason it failed and I was not able to understand the error.

Comment: or in other words write my app

Comment: yup u can even say that :P , but i really tried their sample from http://www.facebook.com/developers/apps.php?app_id=154238604629264&ret=2#

Comment: @Mike                                                          An error occurred with Testing App. Please try again later.

API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.

Comment: Looks like a clear error to me. You're trying to redirect to an external URI, and most likely running into the scam prevention techniques employed by the Facebook engine. Providing some code would help us narrow down the issue.

Comment: i got -1, can u explain why ?

Comment: Check your configuration settings - the app isn't pointing where you want it to be.

Comment: now it -3, i will be happy to see - going to infinity, can u help in that ?

Comment: @JimmySawczuk i can't get you ! can you explain ! i provided the right path for the PHP file !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic FQL approach (using the new [PHP SDK](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/src/facebook.php)):

```
<?php
// assuming we're using the newest version of the Facebook PHP SDK
$fb = new Facebook(array(
     'appId' => '<YOUR_APP_ID>',
     'secret' => '<YOUR_APP_SECRET>'
));

if (!$fb->getSession())
{
    // prompt for install if necessary
    header("Location: ".$fb->getLoginUrl());
}

// Contains basic user information
$user = $fb->api('/me');

// use FQL to get the results
$friends = $fb->api(array(
    'method' => 'fql.query',
    'query' => 'SELECT name, pic_big, pic_small, pic_square 
         FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())'
));
```

[FQL User Table documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/)

Comment: actually i need code + some help where to write this code ? should i store it in my server ?

Comment: <?php
$app_id='***';
$app_secret='***';
$my_url="http://www.web-shine.in/tutorials/test_app.php";
$code=$_REQUEST["code"];
if(empty($code)){
$dialog_url="http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id="
.$app_id."&redirect_uri=".urlencode($my_url);
echo("<script>top.location.href='".$dialog_url."'</script>");
}
$token_url="https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id="
.$app_id."&redirect_uri=".urlencode($my_url)."&client_secret="
.$app_secret."&code=".$code;
$access_token=file_get_contents($token_url);

Comment: Yes, this is PHP, so it gets stored on your server.

Comment: $graph_url="https://graph.facebook.com/me?".$access_token;
$user=json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url));
echo("Hello".$user->name);
?>

Comment: That code isn't defining any app ids or app secrets. Did you omit those intentionally?

Comment: yup, facebook says it should be kept secret !

Comment: Can you do me a favor and paste that code somewhere where we can read it (like your question, with formatting)? I can't read it in comments like that.

Comment: I'm not sure where you got that example from but I'm not sure what part of it is trying to do. I added some functionality that should help you out in my answer.

Comment: should i paste your code and try again ? i mean is it ready to run ?

Comment: I haven't personally tested it, but you're welcome to try it. If it's an error with your app settings (facebook.com/developers) that error will still be in this one. And make sure you include facebook.php from the PHP SDK: https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/src/facebook.php

Comment: **CAN ANYONE HELP ME IN THIS BY STEP BY STEP GUIDE** ? [from CREATE APPLICATION page ]

Answer (score 0):

**If would be nice if you post error & code.**

By the way:

- Facebook application must be hosted on hosting with CURL enabled
- Do you have your correct Developer Key (or how it is called there)?
- Does application code have been just copied from examples? If yes you have to change some things like dev key.
- You will need OAuth, do you have it?

That all i can guess.

Comment: i have my OATH, activation code and the app_key is mine, i just omitted here

Comment: i dont think i have CURL loaded, so i searched and got a list with CURL - EASY, FORM, MULTI, SHARE - which to install ?

Answer (score 0):

need to add the facebook php sdk in the domain www.xyz.com/fb/app
then store the app in it !
and run !

nobody told me that :( :x